# Error COBERTURA in SONAR

Tags: maven, sonarqube

THere are some posts in regards to Sonar/Cobertura but my issue is specific to an error in corbertura plugin. Given below is the error I am getting. I suspect a corbertura library error. Not sure if that is what it is. Any help is appreciated.

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default) on project maple-common: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.ProjectData.getGlobalProjectData()
Lnet/sourceforge/cobertura/coveragedata/ProjectData; -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default) on project maple-common: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.executeForkedExecutions(MojoExecutor.java:365)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:199)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo.execute(ExecJavaMojo.java:352)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:297)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.ProjectData.getGlobalProjectData()Lnet/sourceforge/cobertura/coveragedata/ProjectData;
    at org.xyz.sequoia.mds.dao.tool.MDSDataLoader.main(MDSDataLoader.java:39)
    ... 6 more
```

Here is my pom:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.xyz.sequoia</groupId>
    <artifactId>xyz-sequoia-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</parent>
<groupId>org.xyz.sequoia.maple</groupId>
<artifactId>maple</artifactId>
<version>1.1.0</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>Sequoia - Maple</name>
<description>Sequoia Maple Metadata Distribution Project</description>
<url>http://jira.xyz.org/browse/MPL</url>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <spring.version>3.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <cobertura.version>1.9.4.1</cobertura.version>
    <camel.version>2.11.0</camel.version>
    <junitVersion>4.11</junitVersion>
    <structuredLoggingCoreVersion>1.1</structuredLoggingCoreVersion>
</properties>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>cobertura-instrument</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>cobertura-build</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <modules>
            <module>maple-cobertura</module>
        </modules>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <formats>
                            <format>html</format>
                        </formats>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>instrument-code</id>
                            <phase>process-classes</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>instrument</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <attach>true</attach>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>attach-sources</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <inherited>true</inherited>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sourceforge.cobertura</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-runtime</artifactId>
                <version>${cobertura.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<modules>
    <module>maple-common</module>
    <module>mediator-service</module>
    <module>metadata-delivery</module>
    <module>cassandra</module>
    <module>admin-ui</module>
    <module>data-analysis</module>
    <module>maple-metadata-delivery-web</module>
    <module>id-service</module>
    <module>stub-service</module>
    <module>prepare-ingest</module>
</modules>
```

………………………………….
   ………………………………….
   ………………………………….

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>com.atlassw.tools.eclipse.checkstyle.CheckstyleBuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>com.atlassw.tools.eclipse.checkstyle.CheckstyleNature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalConfig>
                        <file>
                            <name>.checkstyle</name>
                            <content></content>
                        </file>
                    </additionalConfig>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnError>${findbugs.failOnError}</failOnError>
                    <skip>${findbugs.skip}</skip>
                    <trace>${findbugs.trace}</trace>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>findbugs-test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java-version}</source>
                    <target>${java-version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[2.0,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute/>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${coberturaMavenPlugin}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${mavenPmdPlugin}</version>
            <configuration>
                <targetJdk>${javaVersion}</targetJdk>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${findbugsMavenPlugin}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>taglist-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${taglistMavenPlugin}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdepend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jdependPlugin}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${mavenSurefireReportPlugin}</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Comment: I don't know if it'll help but first you should remove <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </plugin>

Comment: Thanks but I removed the Sonar maven exec plugin that was causing issues. Also there were redundant specification of Corbetura plugins in our child pom's that was causing the issue. Removing those helped resolved it.